# Java Swing: HTML form in JEditorPane - text input encoding problem

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JEditorPane` with HTML form and one `<input name="rword" type="text">` inside. I'm getting user input by catching `FormSubmitEvent` with `.getData()` method.

The mystical thing is that, if I run the app in Netbeans IDE, everything is ok - I get URL encoded input in UTF-8, as expected.

But if I run the jar file from command prompt, `getData()` returns the user input in ANSI encoding!

I.e. If I type `ф` in the form, `getData` will return `rword=%D1%84` as expected, but from command line it returns `rword=%F4`! And I didn't find any method to detect encoding. All my experiments with setting content type with `charset=utf-8` have failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in default charset, so run jvm with `file.encoding=UTF-8` option

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar jarfile.jar`